# Connecting two Esper instances running in different JVMs (client / server mode?)

Tags: esper, complex-event-processing

I have one host running a JVM that runs an Esper service. I have another host in which I'd like to connect to the esper service running in the first JVM.

I.e. I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
EPServiceProvider epService = EPServiceProviderManager.getProvider("host1:Processor1");
```

I can't find a way to do this from the documentation, and yet I would have thought it would be a fairly common requirement. How is this sort of thing generally done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esper doesn't really remote the administrative interface. I suppose it depends on exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but if you're trying to insert or listen on events, then I would use one of the Esper/IO services like [Spring JMS](http://esper.codehaus.org/esperio-4.3.0/doc/reference/en/html/adapter_jms_spring.html), [HTTP](http://esper.codehaus.org/esperio-4.3.0/doc/reference/en/html/adapter_http.html) or [Sockets](http://esper.codehaus.org/esperio-4.3.0/doc/reference/en/html/adapter_socket.html).

If you're intent on accessing the service provider directly, you could create a JMX MBean wrapper for the EPServiceProvider and access remotely it over JMX. Most of the return types are remotable, but there are a couple that will not be.